# When using Ping how can i export only the Hostname and IP to excel or csv

Tags: excel, cmd, ip, ping, hostname

new here and hoping someone might be able to help me with this.

I have approximately 200 workstations that have had DHCP reservations completed, I would like to Ping them all and return only the Hostname, IP. If possible to get timed out or, failed also thats a plus but not a necessity.

I want to preface I am no coder. what I have done is create a Bat file to do the mass ping but i am not sure and have not been able to find a solution to export only the Hostname and IP.

I have looked around here and google and found a few VB scripts but I don't understand enough to manipulate them for this need.

I'd like to be able to see something in excel similar to this

testhostname | 192.168.1.1 | Failed/Timedout/pass

Thank you for any assistance you can provide here.

Comment: to get help with your code, show you code. How do you ping 200 workstations? Do you have their names in a file and look for the IP's or do you ping all IP's and want to know, what hostnames come back?

Comment: @stephan 
As of Right now I have a batch file like this. ping CSDMCAM383xxx >> file.csv it returns the full Ping result like this.    

Pinging CSDMCAM5304xxx [10.203.90.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:    
Reply from 10.203.90.xxx: bytes=32 time=144ms TTL=120    
Ping statistics for 10.203.90.xxx:  
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),  


So I know the Hostname and the IP that it should be I would like to just pull out 
CSDMCAM5304xxx | 10.203.90.xxx   If it could also show me Failed/Timedout/pass That would be great.  

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a subroutine (`:getData`) and an example how to use it.

There is no easy way to get all the desired data in one `for` loop (probably doable somehow, but not worth the trouble), so I solved that with two separate pings.

`localhost` and `google` should return successful, `hp` is up but doesn't reply to `ping` and `xxxxxxx.zzz` does not exist (yet)

```
@echo off
setlocal 
for %%h in (localhost www.google.com www.hp.com xxxxxxx.zzz) do call :getData %%h
goto :eof

:getData
set "ip=unresolved"
set "ms=unreachable"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %1') do set "ip=%%a"
for /f "tokens=3 delims==<" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 4 %1^|find "TTL="') do set "ms=%%a"
set "result=%1^|%ip%^|%ms%"
set "result=%result: TTL=%"
set "result=%result:||=|unknown|%
echo %result%
```

Output:

```
localhost|127.0.0.1|1ms
www.google.com|172.217.22.100|13ms
www.hp.com|15.73.200.24|unreachable
xxxxxxx.zzz|unresolved|unreachable
```

So as you mentioned, that takes a while with 200 hosts. We can speed it up by running the different hosts simultaneously (that's the biggest change and also the biggest effect). I also reduced Waittime from standard 1000ms down to 200ms and the number of pings from 4 to 2 (I wouldn't reduce that any further because sometimes a package gets lost and cause a false negative). Also with that many of hosts, you will hit the max line length with this method. Better keep the hostnames in a file (one per line) (`hostnames.txt`):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
if not "%~1" == "" goto :getData
for /f %%h in (hostnames.txt) do start /min "pinging %%~h" /min "%~f0" %%~h
echo waiting for result.csv to fill...
REM because some of the started processes are still running
timeout 5
goto :eof

:getData
set "ip=unresolved"
set "ms=unreachable"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 -w 200 %~1') do set "ip=%%a"
for /f "tokens=3 delims==<" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 2 -w 200 %~1^|find "TTL="') do set "ms=%%a"
set "result=%~1^|%ip%^|%ms%"
set "result=%result: TTL=%"
echo %result%>>"%~dp0result.csv"
exit
```

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding would your third line look like this for me using the Hostnames I have.  
    `for %%h in (localhost CSDMCAM5463xxx CSDMCAM5304xxx CSDMCAM5304xxx) do call :getData %%h
goto :eof`       Sorry still trying to figure out how to use the correct markdown. - How can I tell this to export to a .csv.  where can I add >>file.csv

Comment: For 200 hosts, with this method you will hit some hard limit (max line length). If you have them in a file (one per line): `for /f %%h in (file.txt) do call  :getdata %%h`. For export: `echo %result% >> file.csv`.

Comment: @Stephen

This is great!  Thank you.  One last comment.  using this method it runs very slow took about 30 sec-1 min for 1 hostname.  Going on 13 min right now for 7 out of 13 on my test. -  Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: @Jason it's nearly midnight at my corner of the world. Let me sleep a bit and think about it tomorrow `:O`

Comment: @stephen

Thank you, No rush, Appreciate you helping out with this

Comment: thank you,  I will give this a shot tomorrow when I get in.  Appreciate you taking the time to put this together.